# Problem with \usepackage{caption}. The error: "Undefined control sequence in \caption" comes up. If \usepackage{caption} is removed pdf shows no error

Tags: floats, errors, captions, subcaption

```
\documentclass[msom,nonblindrev]{informs3}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,positioning,calc}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    
        \caption{Figure A}
        \label{Figure A}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

```
File: t1cmss.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
! Undefined control sequence.
\setstretch ...ef \baselinestretch {#1}\@currsize 
                                                  
l.181 \caption{Figure A}
```

Comment: Which class are you using?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You don't mention the document class. If I complete with `article`, I have no problem, so I guess this is linked to the class.

Comment: Unrelated you should not use the center env to center inside a float. It adds vertical space as does the float it self. Replace `\begin{center}` by `\centering` and remove `\end{center}`.

Comment: I am using document class @Bernard

Comment: @Anannya You need to mention the document class type, like `article`, `book`, or anything else.

Comment: Article class type @Imran

Comment: Other packages that I have used are-

Comment: \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{exscale}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
\makeatletter \g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds} \makeatother
\usepackage{multirow}

Comment: don't add code in comments (as you see it does not work well) also don't post fragments of code in your question, edit the question to be a complete small document that shows the error, just include the packages needed to show the error. Also show the exact error message from the log (which will show which command is undefined)

Comment: unrelated to your question but no document written after 1994 should be using epsfig package

Comment: Your error message shows that the standard latex  `\@currsize` is not defined which means that LaTex has not yet selected a font.  Clearly the code you post has not selected a font as you have no `\documentclass{article}` (which does `\normalsize` so the document starts at 10pt)   but in that case, the first error is `! LaTeX Error: \usepackage before \documentclass.`  Please edit your code so that the error shown is the first error. `\@currsize` should never be undefined as there should always be a current font at that size.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks a lot. I tried changing  \documentclass[msom,nonblindrev]{informs3} to \documentclass[12pt]{article} and the code is running perfectly.

Comment: so your issue is in the informs3 class which you had not even mentioned, Please _always_ provide a test file that shows the problem, otherwise no one can answer.

Answer (score 4):

The class intentionally disables all the standard font size commands but leaves latex in a rather broken state. A quick fix to define `\normalsize` and the internal current-font-size command `\@currsize` to be no-op is as follows.

```
\documentclass[msom,nonblindrev]{informs3}
\makeatletter
\let\normalsize\relax
\let\@currsize\normalsize
\makeatother
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,positioning,calc}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    
        \caption{Figure A}
        \label{Figure A}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @David Carlisle. This is working perfectly fine now.