# Adding caption and label to an annotated figure with `tikzpicture`

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, labels, annotations

I would like to annotate a figure, so I used `tikzpicture` inside a figure environment like this

```
\documentclass[msom,nonblindrev]{informs3}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{fig}};
\node[align=center,black] at (1,1) {annotation};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{figCaption}\label{figLabel}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It works well without the `\caption{figCaption}\label{figLabel}` but when I run it with this line, I get the error `! Undefined control sequence.`

Could someone help with this please?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: If I guess enough code to make your code fragment compilable, it works just fine. We really need to see actual code which reproduces the problem. Otherwise you'll just get low quality answers which are unrelated to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. In fact, the problem was using `\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}`!

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. Can you make a short example document which reproduces the problem?

Comment: There seems to be a problem between `setspace` and `subcaption` when I use `informs3` because with `article` they work fine. I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Using this MWE that is similar to your fragment, it works well. What are your mistakes in the `.log` file?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
\node[align=center,black] at (1,1) {annotation};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{figCaption}\label{figLabel}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. When I remove `\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}` from my code, it works well.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same problem as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/612744/36296

You can work around it by providing a definition for `\@currsize`. The following one by @DavidCarlisle shouldn't have any negative effects on the document:

```
\documentclass[msom,nonblindrev]{informs3}

\makeatletter
\let\normalsize\relax
\let\@currsize\normalsize
\makeatother

\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-duck}};
\node[align=center,black] at (1,1) {annotation};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{figCaption}\label{figLabel}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]